# Ajax запрос не отсылает данные

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть вот такая функция (навешана на button.onclick):

```
function addNewUser() {
    var dataToSend = "";
    dataToSend += "name=" + $("#name").val();
    dataToSend += "&email=" + $("#email").val();
    dataToSend += "&login=" + $("#username").val();
    dataToSend += "&pass=" + $("#password").val();
    alert(dataToSend);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "registration.ashx",
        // данные, которые будут отправлятся на сервер с запросом
        data: dataToSend,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
};
```

dataToSend заполняется корректно. Сам запрос тоже происходит, но dataToSend не доходит к registration.ashx.

Код registration.ashx:

```
public class registration : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        var parametrs = context.Request.QueryString;
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        // проверка параметров
        if (parametrs["login"] == "user" && parametrs["pass"] == "12345")
        {
            // отправка ответа
            context.Response.Write("Авторизация прошла успешно");
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.Write("Ошибка авторизации");
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

В результате всегда возвращается ошибка авторизации. Уже голову сломал - в чем дело?

Comment: что пишет консоль? данные уходят? массивом/объектом отправлять не пробовали? мазохизм так строку формировать))

Comment: Передавать дополнительные параметры с помощю аякса вроде так нужно `data: {name:value},` где name- имя переменной, а value- значение переменной

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk глянь в доки, string/object/array.

Answer (score 1):

Данные в `POST` запросе передаются не в `QueryString`, a в теле запроса.

Сделайте на клиенте:

```
url: "registration.ashx?" + dataToSend,
```

или на сервере:

```
var parametrs = context.Request;
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать `data` оформить в виде объекта и с сервера возвращать `json`:

javascript:

```
function addNewUser() {
    var data = {
        name: $("#name").val(),
        email: $("#email").val(),
        login: $("#username").val(),
        pass: $("#password").val()
    };
    alert(data);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "registration.ashx",
        dataType: 'json' // ожидаем с сервера json
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            if (response && response.result === 'success') {} else {}
            alert(response);
        }
    });
};
```

c#:

```
/* ... */
context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
/* ... */
context.Response.Write("{ \"result\": \"success\", \"msg\": \"Авторизация прошла успешно\" }");
```